# Android Studio says to use Gradle 1.10 - but new version is 1.12?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

The error:

```
The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.  Please use version 1.10.


My `gradle.build` file says this:

dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
}
```

As far as I know, the above line is correct. My `gradle-wrapper` file says:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

This happened when I downloaded the newest Android Studio beta (v.8) and tried to import an app that had, what I assume is an old version of Gradle.

Also, when I hit "`Fix Gradle Wrapper and re-import project`", nothing happens.

Comment: Try bumping your `buildToolsVersion` to `"19.1.0"` (or higher, if there's something higher than that).

Comment: @CommonsWare  Thanks for the suggestion.  It was 19.0.0.  I made it 19.1.0.  Same thing.

Comment: Are you using the latest Android SDK Tools? Currently, it is Rev. 23.0.2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to change the gradle-wrapper to a lower version you have to change distributionUrl to

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

and then rerun the wrapper task. If this isn't enough just delete the folders `.gradle` and `gradle` and the files `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat`.
The rerun wrapper and he downloads gralde 1.10

Since gradle had some major api changes from version 1.10 and 1.12 you can not build any project with a higher version then the plugins are build with. So if the android plugin is build with gradle 1.10 you have to use the same version

Comment: Hey thanks, that worked.  It took the part where I had to delete those 4 exact folders and files.

Answer (score 1):

**Error:** "Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.0"

**Why it show:** Attempting to build an Android project that requires 1.10 version of Gradle while using 2.0 version of it as native.

**What should be done to resolve this problem:** Updating the gradle version within **build.gradle** file

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2+'
}
```

**replacing it with**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between Gradle version and Gradle Android Plugin version (0.12.+).
Looks like you need Gradle version 1.10, don't think later versions are supperted by the Gradle Android plugin yet. Anyway, I think making sure that you use Gradle 1.10 version will resolve this issue.

Comment: Where are you able to upgrade/change the actual Gradle version?  Edit:  It looks like this is set in Gradle Wrapper I think.  I try to change it there and nothing happens.  When I try to re-sync, it goes back to 1.12.

Comment: Not sure that wrapper will support rolling back to previous versions, i would try to uninstall Gradle alltogether and install the correct version only.

Comment: Is it possible to just blow away all the Gradle setting in the project and AS will auto rebuild it if I resetup the project?

Comment: I think it'll only take care of the Android Gradle plugin. Pretty sure it will use the existing Gradle installation, which is the wrong version in your case.

Comment: gradle 1.12 works fine with gradle android plugin 0.11+