# Gradle project refresh failed (AS 0.8.2, Mac)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

With a blank new project, I get this:

```
Gradle 'HelloWorld' project refresh failed
    Error:Cause: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

When trying to build I get the following Gradle Build error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloWorld'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+.
     Required by:
         :HelloWorld:unspecified
      > org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

This is a fresh installation of Android Studio, and my build.gradle looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

The first lines of the relevant log error are:

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloWorld'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloWorld'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+.
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

The project structure is just the default for a new project with a blank activity:

[image: Project structure screenshot]

Comment: can you show use a screenshot of your project structure?

Comment: @DiscoS2 The project structure is the default for a new project with a blank activity, so that shouldn't be a problem, but I have uploaded a screenshot as requested

Comment: did you try a refresh install?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio/18458893#18458893

Answer (score 4):

For me it look like incompatible versions. So this problem is related to this problem: [Android Studio says to use Gradle 1.10 - but new version is 1.12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460299/android-studio-says-to-use-gradle-1-10-but-new-version-is-1-12)

Try to use gradle 1.10 and delete the the folder of the gradle wrapper.

Comment: This answer might help too upgrading your Gradle version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252956/android-studio-gradle-issue-upgrading-to-version-0-5-0-gradle-migrating-from-0/22252957#22252957

Answer (score -1):

Try mavenCentral() instead of jcenter()

Looks like this is a known issue..
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73511

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Then it should be something related to gradle wrapper. It is worth checking this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673636/gradle-error-could-not-execute-build-using-gradle-distribution

Comment: I have tried all of the solutions listed on that page, and none of them have worked.