# AndroidStudio (0.8.9 Mac) New Project Gradle Failed to Sync

Tags: android, macos, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm kind of blocked during my evaluation of Android Studio (0.8.9 on Mac) due to a gradle synchronization error.

I have already searched for other issues like that on StackOverflow (such as [Gradle project refresh failed (AS 0.8.2, Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786604/gradle-project-refresh-failed-as-0-8-2-mac)) but without finding a solution.

Immediately when I create a new Android project using Android Studio, I got the following error:

> Error:Unable to find method 'org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process may be corrupt.
>     Stop Gradle daemons and sync project
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

My build.gradle file is the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
      // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
   }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and gradle-wrapper.properties is:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

I hope you can help me to find a solution.

Thanks

Marco

Comment: I recommend adding gradle tag instead of sync

Comment: See if this answer solves your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874743/gradle-project-refresh-failed-after-android-studio-update

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick responses. Unfortunately, the solution in the suggested link, doesn't work for me. (I can't add "grandle" tag due to my StackOverflow ranking)

Comment: That's because it's gradle, not grandle.

Comment: I have opened an issue on Google Code. You can follow the discussion at: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=77366

Answer (score 7):

I hava same question with you .Now ,I finished. you can delete file in "C:\Users\47.gradle"("47" is my account name ),Android stuido will download new file and then unzip it.