# Android Studio - Could not determine Java version

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed a fresh copy of Android Studio using terminal but when i create a new project it gives the error 
"Could not determine Java Version".
JDK and SDK both are installed.
Android Studio is updated to the latest version.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply changed default java JDK from Oracle JDK to OpenJDK. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 83):

Change this:

```
targetCompatibility 'JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8'
sourceCompatibility 'JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8'
```

to this:

```
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

Comment: Weird Solution, but works! I guess it is a typo error in AS 3.4

Comment: I think this is a change in the new Android studio. They want to use the JavaVersion as an object and not a string

Comment: where to change? Where can we find target and source compatibility?

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue, but on windows 7 OS. It was because multiple versions of java was present in the same location `C:\Program Files\Java` Java 5, 7, 8, and 9. Although the Environment variables JAVA_HOME and PATH were set to Java 8, Android studio was referring to Java 9.

My Solution, in the menu, click on `File > Project Structure` here, point JDK to appropriate location `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk`

Comment: same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756186/gradle-wrapper-get-wrong-java-version-in-android-project-on-windows) for me, but after assigning proper jdk location, gradle still find a wrong java version.

Answer (score 3):

One potential problem is that older versions of Gradle can't parse the Java version from the `java -version` output produced by the OpenJDK. Newer versions can (I think it was updated around Gradle 2.2; the latest, 2.9, works).

Comment: see this on how to change the gradle version when using the default wrapper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205113/how-to-change-the-version-of-the-default-gradle-wrapper-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 3):

change distributionUrl in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to new version of gradle

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try that if the error occurs again.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, in ubuntu 16. It was because multiple versions of java was present in the same location 7, 8 and 9. Although the Environment variables JAVA_HOME and PATH were set to Java 8, Android studio was referring to Java 9.

My Solution, in the menu, click on File > Project Structure here, select 8 version

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the JAVA_HOME environment? run `echo $JAVA_HOME` in your terminal and see if you get a valid path to your Java binaries.

if not, set the the JAVA_HOME:

```
nano .bashrc
```

Add the lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path to jdk>
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Save the file and then reload the .bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I already have a variable. The command returns "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
"

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Keds's answer. In android Studio, in Project Tab/File Explorer go to 
*Gradle Scripts* -> *gradle.properties*

You will see something like this:

```
#Sat Sep 21 13:08:26 CEST 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

The distributionURL is old and, I'm assuming based on other answers, could not parse the Java version appropriately.

So picked a newer version by going to this site: 
http://services.gradle.org/distributions/

I picked

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8.1-all.zip
```

just because. There are newer versions, such as 4.10.2, but I'm not really using gradle, it's just required for the project.

Also, although it didn't really affect me running my project, my project wasn't pointing to the new JDK. It was pointing to Android Studio's jre file automatically as recommended.

If you want to change this, get the file path location of the newest Java JDK. Usually in

```
C:\Program Files\Java\your_jdk_file
```

for windows.
In Android Studio, go to File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location.

Uncheck 'Embedded JDK (recommended)', then paste the file path to the newest JDK file path for the entire file.

Such as

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2
```

And not just the bin file. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of this worked for me so in case it can help someone else :
Right click on "app" in your project, go to "Open Module Settings">"Properties" and change the source compatibility and target compatibility to the Java version you need.

Answer (score 0):

well ,what solved the problem for me is that i didn't use embeded jdk and then set java version to java 7 and build it gave me error because of lambda expression then i set java version to 1.8 and sync then build and it worked

Answer (score 0):

While opening an old android project with latest version of the android studio many compilation errors occur. However, following steps worked for me to update the project settings and build scripts.

Open File->Project Structure and make sure that

1. you have selected the latest versions of the Android Gradle Plugin and **Gradle version**
2. CompileSdkVersion and **targetSdkVersion** are same
3. **compileSdkVerrion** and buildToolsVersion are compatible (if not exactly same)

In the project level **build.gradle** file make sure **google()** is added to the repositories for buildscript{} and **allprojects{}**.

In the module level **build.gradle** file, replace the word **compile** with **implementation** and **testCompile** with **testImplementation**.  In the **compileOptions{}** block **remove** the single quotes from around the JavaVersion… string.

Synchronize again and make the project.