# Flutter is showing lot of error after updating android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I updated android studio to 4.1 yesterday after that I can't run projects in flutter . On flutter doctor the errors are showing as in the screen shot given below. But my flutter and dart plugins are installed already .Anyone please help me

[Screen shot of flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI9pj.png)

Comment: It seems that you forgot to add screenshot

Comment: Upload your screenshot so we can able to check the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable dart support for the project and get all dependencies.
It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this question :

[Flutter plugin not installed error. When running flutter doctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860845/flutter-plugin-not-installed-error-when-running-flutter-doctor)

[Solving Android Toolchain problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796797/android-studio-could-not-determine-java-version)