# IntelliJ contains old version of Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea

I have created Spring Initializr project with Gradle support in my IntelliJ IDEA on my Windows machine. When wizzard finishes I'm getting error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\java_test\crudwithvaadin\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']
   > Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 5 (5.6.x only) or Gradle 6 (6.3 or later). The current version is Gradle 5.2.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Does it means IntelliJ contains old version of Gradle? How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Check what the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file contains, e.g.:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip`.

Under `Preferences` > `Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle` you will find the default settings which are probably set to `gradle-wrapper.properties`. You can change it to specific version of gradle.

[image]

Also check [How to change the version of the 'default gradle wrapper' in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205113/how-to-change-the-version-of-the-default-gradle-wrapper-in-intellij-idea) and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_settings_access