# The supplied phased action failed with an exception : minimum supported Gradle version is 7.5. Current version is 7.4.2

Tags: java, android, spring, flutter, gradle

I primarily work with Flutter, and I recently configured my system for the Spring framework in Java. However, I've been encountering an issue in every Flutter project I work on. Despite the fact that the projects build and run successfully, there's a persistent warning that's been bothering me.

The warning message I receive is as follows:
[image]

> The supplied phased action failed with an exception. A problem occurred configuring the root project 'android'. A problem occurred when evaluating the root project 'android'. A problem occurred configuring the project ':app'. A problem occurred when evaluating the project ':app'. It failed to apply the 'com.android.internal.version-check' plugin, stating that the minimum supported Gradle version is 7.5, while the current version is 7.4.2. If you are using the Gradle wrapper, you might want to consider editing the 'distributionUrl' in the 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file located at 'E:\APPFLOWY\1\AppFlowy\frontend\appflowy_flutter\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties' to 'gradle-7.5-all.zip'."

Comment: Just upgrade the gradle wrapper to the version mentioned in the error message: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36385128/150978

Comment: Have you tried following the advice in the error message? It seems pretty clear.